# Does git checkout pull changes from origin?

Tags: git

I am writing a deployment script, this is what it does:

```
# Fetches all branches and tags
git fetch origin
# Checkout the branch/tag
git checkout 2.1.0
```

**If 2.1.0 is a tag**

I guess I have the latest version available since a tag can't change, so everything is good.

**If 2.1.0 is a branch**

If this is the first time I checkout the branch, I guess everything is good (I'll be getting the most up to date version of the code).

If the branch has already been checked out, does the `git checkout` command checks out the remote branch, or the local branch? -> **do I need to pull to get the latest version of the code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need `git pull` or at least `git merge origin/2.1.0`.

Indeed, `git fetch` pulls down the latest code from remote to `origin/branch` at local. If you have no local branch with the same name, then `git checkout 2.1.0` will create it for you, and checkout to that branch. **But**, if you have one already, then `git checkout 2.1.0` will just checkout to the local branch as normal.

Indeed, a branch `2.1.0`, `origin/2.1.0`, or a tag `2.1.0`, they are all pointers, point to a specific commit. Here `2.1.0` point to the local latest commit of branch `2.1.0` while `origin/2.1.0` point to the remote latest commit.

Comment: Thanks, very clear answer! What is the difference between `git pull` and `git merge origin/branch` in this case then?

Comment: Indeed, `git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`, it fetch the code and merge it to current branch. As you have executed `git fetch` first, so a simple `git merge` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Once you execute 'git fetch'
fetch download all the branches and their content (object) so you can keep working offline.

if you already have local branch named 2.1.0 if will switch to the locat branch
if you don't have local branch then you can use 'git checkout -b [new_branch_name]' which will checkout, create and switch to your new branch.